# What are the guidelines on when to use `Surface` vs `Background` color in Material 3 design?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have an app with bottom navigation bar that contains different screens the user can select. It is not clear whether i should use `Surface` or `Background` color in [Material 3](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/color-roles#0abbf8b7-61e1-49ee-9f97-4967beb1e4fe) colors as the default canvas for the screen.

I also have a log in screen and registration and don't know if i should use the same color in the "background" as the above sheets.

Does anyone have any advice or rule of thumbs i can follow to decide when to use `Surface` and when to use `Background` color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [further reading](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/tokens) the Material 3 guidelines, it mentions:

`Note: Background is a legacy color role. It is recommended to use Surface instead of Background.`.

Hence the guidelines prefer to use `Surface`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per guidelines for Android Wear:

- Surface colors map to components such as cards, sheets, and menus
- Background color is found behind scrollable content